# No page number or negative page number in ExtJS BufferedStore request . Also value for start is -15

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, store, infinite-scroll

I have a grid with buffered store. 
Configs are as follows :

```
buffered = true;
pageSize = 15;
trailingBufferZone = 0;
leadingBufferZone = 0;
purgePageCount = 0;
```

But sometimes page number in store load request is negative or 0 , this causes grid to show continuous loading . In this case , totalCount is coming but there are no records in response. Also start value is negative sometimes[image]

I debugged in BufferedStore.js and found , there is a code in `prefetch`  method to fetch page number as

```
if (!options.page) {
            options.page = me.getPageFromRecordIndex(options.start);
            options.start = (options.page - 1) * pageSize;
            options.limit = Math.ceil(options.limit / pageSize) * pageSize;
  }
```

and

```
   getPageFromRecordIndex: function(index) {
            return Math.floor(index / this.getPageSize()) + 1;
     },
```

This `getPageFromRecordIndex` method return value as 0 so assigning options.page as 0.

parameters to this methos are as follows here :

```
index = 15 and pageSize = 15;
```

Any help ? Thanks in advance.